# How do I loop two array as one in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have a probrem but I don't  know how to fix it,

here is two array

first is`$X = A,B,C,D`
second likes this `a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]`

I want to loop likes this

```
Aa[1]a[2]

Ba[3]a[4]

Ca[5]a[6]

Da[7]a[8]
```

now i write likes this

```
foreach($X as $key) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $a[$i];
    }
    $g=$a[$key][$i];
}
```

But it isn't that thing I want.

how can I fix it? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for

```
<?php
$X = ['A','B','C','D'];
$Y = ['a[1]a[2]','a[3]a[4]','a[5]a[6]','a[7]a[8]'];

$result = [];
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($X) ; $i++) { 
    $result[] = $X[$i].$Y[$i];
 }
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Aa[1]a[2]
    [1] => Ba[3]a[4]
    [2] => Ca[5]a[6]
    [3] => Da[7]a[8]
)
```